# Building dependencies in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, dependencies, xcode4

I have a project that has a dependency on a static library. In Xcode 3.2.3 the project that builds the library is setup as a direct dependency in the target settings so that the library is built whenever the main project is built.

I can't for the life of me figure out how this is supposed to work in Xcode 4. I haven't changed any project/target settings but the dependent library will not build. Has anyone successfully setup library dependencies so that they automatically build in Xcode 4?

Comment: Isn't Xcode 4 still under NDA?

Comment: Log on to Apple's developer forum to discuss NDA software legally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without breaking NDA, I highly recommend watching the [WWDC 2010 videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) for session 308 - Developing Your App with Xcode 4 and session 314 - Building and Distributing Your App with Xcode 4.  Setting up dependencies in Xcode 4 is demonstrated in these videos.

If those videos are unable to answer your specific questions, I recommend heading over to the [Apple Developer Forums](http://devforums.apple.com/) to ask the engineers themselves.

Comment: I'll check those out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I write article on topic. [Check this out](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=14XR5zcZb2Kz2s6A4AbzB00NLkrW9bWxMMprVsUao-hY).

Comment: thanks, silly I am, I was missing setting Target Dependencies :)